# Can't connect to DB located in docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to create PostgreSQL DB inside docker container and connect to it from my local machine. Running `docker-compose up -d` with that inside `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12.2
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: db
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
```

ended successfully. No crashes, errors of something. But, when I'm trying to connect to it with `pgAdmin4` with these credentials:

- Host name/address: localhost
- Port: 5432
- Maintenance database: db
- Username: root
- Password: root

it says to me:

> Unable to connect to server:
>
> FATAL: password authentication failed for user "root"

---

My OS: Windows 10 build(1809)

PostgreSQL version (installed on local machine): 12

Docker version: 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d

---

UPD 1:

After re-creating container with different ports (now it is 5433:5433), `pgAdmin4` error changed:

> Unable to connect to server:
>
> server closed the connection unexpectedly
> This probably means the server terminated abnormally
> before or while processing the request.

Comment: What is the output of `docker-compose logs`?

Comment: @akop, https://pastebin.com/cCaEvyCb. cutted how DB is initializing

Comment: You can check if db, user/pwd creation is successful by doing `docker exec` inside that container and executing `psql -U root -d db` and see if connnection establishes

Comment: You installed Postgres on your local maschine? Maybe you trying to connect to wrong database.

Comment: @Wander3r works great inside container, no errors

Answer (score 0):

> Host name/address: localhost

> Port: 5432

You are trying to connect to 5432 port on localhost. Are you sure your container is taking the host IP?

To make the container run with the host IP run the container with --network host option.

```
docker run --network host <rest of the command>
```

Note that if you use '--network host' option, then portmapping '-p' option is not needed.
Read https://docs.docker.com/network/host/ for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked you've cleaned away any old instances running locally and that you're not trying to access an old instance?

You can wipe out all local docker containers with: `docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)`

Once you've got a clean environment you can try spin up the containers again locally and see if you can access the service. I copy/pasted what you have into a clean `docker-compose.yaml` and ran `docker-compose up` against the file - it worked and I logged in and was able to view the `pg_user` table.

If it still fails you can try to find the IP using: `netstat -in | grep en0` which will show something like

`en0   1500  192.168.1     **192.168.1.163**   15301832     -  9001208 - - -`

this shows the external/accessible IP of the container. Try using the address shown (something similar to 192.168.1.163) instead of `localhost`